# CSS box-shadow inset gap between border when collapsed border

Tags: html, css

I have a table with border-collapse: collapse set, and the result is an odd gap between the the box-shadow inset and the border, which gets bigger with bigger border widths.  How do I avoid this weirdness?  This is on Chrome, by the way.

HTML:

```
<table class="theTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="weirdGap">
      unexpected gap
      <br>
      unexpected gap
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.theTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;

}

.weirdGap {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px red;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

Here's the jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ukhgK/11/

Answer (score 0):

The border-collapse property sets the table borders are collapsed into a single border or detached as in standard HTML. You can find more [developer.mozilla.org/.../border-collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse) how to use it with examples.

Comment: I should mention that I do understand what border-collapse does.  My question was rather why does having a collapsed border introduce a weird gap between inset box-shadows.  Unfortunately the link you provided gives no information on this odd behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This problem still persists, so here’s a work-around that might work depending on your needs: Instead of `border-collapse: collapse;` create all borders of the table using box-shadow:

```
box-shadow:
    inset 1px 0 black,
    inset 0 1px black,
    1px 0 0 0 black,
    0 1px 0 0 black,
    1px 1xp 0 0 black;
```

This leads to the borders on the right on bottom protruding out from the cell’s box whereas the borders on the top and left stay within the box. With `cell-spacing: 0`, borders of neighboring boxes fall on-top of each other, creating a similar effect to `border-collapse: collapse`. You can now use additional box shadows to achieve the effects you want, just remember that you need to repeat all existing shadows you want to keep. (I.e. if you have `box-shadow` properties on the same cell from two different rules, they’re not combined automatically and you need to write the rule that combines them manually.)